# What is fetch command on ubuntu?

Tags: webrtc

I tried to install webrtc-streamer on my AM4372(Ti)chips ARM-based board. I need to execute

```
fetch webrtc
```

I ran this command, then the following error occured. I don't  get the meaning of the message. please explain what fecth command is.

```
"-bash: fetch: command not found"
```

Comment: It's a message from `bash` (your shell) that the command `fetch` doesn't exist. It isn't installed (or installed incorrectly).

Answer (score 2):

> **What is fetch command on ubuntu?**

`fetch` is not a standard command on Ubuntu.

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

$ type time
time is a shell keyword

$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'

$ type git
git is /usr/bin/git

$ type fetch
-bash: type: fetch: not found
```

---

It is likely that the [instructions you are following](https://github.com/mpromonet/webrtc-streamer) have omitted to mention some non-standard prerequisites that must be installed first.

---

> **I don't get the meaning of the message `-bash: fetch: command not found`**

The command shell, bash, is telling you that it cannot find a command named "fetch" or it is reporting an error returned by a fetch command it did find.

This general sort of error message can occur when the command does not exist or when it is the name of a program that is not in the current `$PATH`.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/1334601/52492